Jenkins pipeline httpRequest step - Get content of error response
I'm using httpRequest step in my pipelines - and it generally works fine.  However I'm struggling to get the content of a response when the response is an error.  In my logic, I need to actually read the content of the error response, as that contains JSON, which drives the next steps in the logic.  Using response.content only works on the successful response.
Is there any way to get the error response content from this step?

If you don't mind the httpRequest step being marked as successful for non-200 responses you can provide validResponseCodes parameter to treat those response codes as valid.
